# Create jqGrid Dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, foreach

I have a JSON string which I'd like to loop and create a separate jqGrid for each record...

```
+--------------------------+
| Grid for 1st JSON record |
+--------------------------+

+--------------------------+
| Grid for 2nd JSON record |
+--------------------------+

+--------------------------+
| Grid for 3rd...          |
+--------------------------+
```

Not sure how to go about doing this.  Thinking maybe jQuery $.each() and then 'do stuff'... but not sure what the 'do stuff' needs to be.

Maybe there's a way to do this with jqGrid only.  Not sure.

Ideas??

Thanks!

=== EDIT ===
Sample data...
{
"0":{"id":"4216","action":"1"},
"1":{"id":"1218","action":"12"},
"2":{"id":"7783","action":"3"},
"3":{"id":"9656","action":"7"},
}

=== EDIT ===
Forgot to include versions.  jqSuitePHP_4_4_4_0 and jquery-2.0.0.js

Comment: Could you post an example of "JSON string" with input data? Do you mean "1st row of the Grid created based on the 1st JSON record" instead on "Grid for 1st JSON record" or you mean that you need create multiple grids: one grid per "JSON record"?

Comment: Sample data added to question.  I actually need each "record" to be a separate grid.